# Coervive Map on a Banach Space

Tags: optimization, banach-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, coercive

If $B$ is a finite-dimensional Banach space then norm-coercivity and coercivity coincide since the weak and strong topologies coincide.  However, if $B$ is infinite-dimensional, say $B=L^p$ for $p\in [1,\infty]$, then what are some examples of coercive functions on $B$?

Comment: What are the two notions of coercivity you're distinguishing between? I've only heard of $f:B\to \left]-\infty,+\infty\right]$ being coercive if $\lim_{\|x\|\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$

Comment: @Zim but this is equivalent to coercivity in the weak topology.  Since the level-sets $\{x \in L^p: f(x)<=t\}$ are not compact (by Banach-Alaoglou).  This is the definition of coercivity in general settings.

Comment: Oh ok so the two definitions are the limit and compactness of the level sets? Interesting. Well kindof by definition, the $L^p$ norm be a coercive function on $B$